# Size guidelines for Cast Styled Media Receiver image assets (backgrounds, logos, etc.)?

Tags: google-cast

Are there any guidelines as to the optimum size for the various image assets that one can customize in the Styled Media Receiver (background, logo, splash, watermark, etc.)? The only thing I can find in the Cast [styled media receiver documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver) is that the example CSS for the `watermark` is specified with a `background-size` of `57px` by `57px`.

In particular, not having any other guidelines, I tried using a background image of 1920 x 1080 and find that the app takes way too long to start up on my Chromecast. Also my logo image, which is 300x300, seems a bit too large to me when on-screen.

Answer (score 3):

The video image art is 96x143 pixels, the audio album art is 384x384, the fullscreen size should be considered 1280x720, the watermark is 57x57.